# Javascript error in safari - null is not an object

Tags: javascript, safari

Im trying to make a simple image gallery for my website.
Its a bunch of images in a `<ul>` and each image as a `<li>` element.
I have a javascript onclick event that passes the next image number and changes the element style from display block to display none.
Its working perfectly in Firefox etc, but not in Safari. When the gallery is at the last image, and is supposed to go back around and show the first image, nothing happens. the last image just dissapears and i get an error that says: "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(image).style')"

Here is my html (I have removed the file paths etc, just to make it shorter:

```
<ul id='img-container'>

<li id='1' class='first' style='display: block;'><a onclick='changeImage(2)'><img src='' /></a></li>

<li id='2' style='display: none;'><a onclick='changeImage(3)'><img src=''/></a></li>

<li id='3' style='display: none;'><a onclick='changeImage(4)'><img src='' /></a></li>

<li id='4' style='display: none;'><a onclick='changeImage(5)'><img src='' /></a></li>

<li id='5' style='display: none;'><a onclick='changeImage(6)'><img src=''/></a></li>

<li id='6' style='display: none;'><a onclick='changeImage(7)'><img src=''/></a></li>
</ul>
```

and here is the javascript:

```
    function countTotalImages(listName){
    var list = document.getElementById(listName);
    var numberOfImages = 0;
    var i = 0;
    while(list.getElementsByTagName('li') [i++]) numberOfImages++;
    return numberOfImages;
}

function changeImage(imageNumber) {
    var image = imageNumber;
    var totalImages = countTotalImages('img-container');
    var currentImage = image - 1;
    if (image > totalImages) {
        image = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById(currentImage).style.display='none';
    document.getElementById(image).style.display='block';

}
```

The funny thing is that if i change the variable "totalImages" in the if statement to 6, which is the total number of images in the list, then it works in safari. But I need it to be variable, as its not always the same amount of images in the gallery.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

xM

Comment: What's wrong with `list.getElementsByTagName('li').length`?!

Comment: Perfect, that fixed my problem. And much cleaner code. Thank you! :)